# Is there any Google REST API OR any way to get all the Firebase Remote Config Condition/Cohorts/Parameter list created?

Tags: firebase, firebase-remote-config, firebase-ab-testing

I want :

1. To get **condition/cohorts/parameter** which are created inside remote config OR A/b testing to show that conditions list at our front-end just like Firebase.
2. Crete a condition or cohort from REST API.
3. Get which cohorts are the applicable to the user just like remote config fetches the data depending upon cohort in which user falls.

Please suggest any way to do so.

For more clarity :

I want to create a Panel where the admin selects the cohorts for any feature and then user gets that feature access depending upon the cohort in which he falls.

I checked the Remote Config REST API docs but did not find any relevant solution.

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/remote-config/automate-rc#get_the_current_remote_config_template?